# Variável da sessão não existe

Tags: php, session

Há uns dias relatei um problema que estava acontecendo no código que estava utilizando, mas como faltava muitas coisas nele decidi utilizar outro. No novo código, existem as variáveis para salvar a sessão, como está abaixo:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
  // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
  echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
  // Salva os dados encontrados na variável $resultado
  $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

  // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
  $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
  $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
  $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];

  // Redireciona o visitante
  header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
}
```

Já o código da página de restrição, há os seguintes códigos:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
  // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
  echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
 } else {
  // Salva os dados encontrados na variável $resultado
  $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

  // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
  $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
  $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
  $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];

  // Redireciona o visitante
  header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
}
```

Porém ao inserir usuário e senha como pedem na página de teste que fiz para rodar os códigos, surge a seguinte mensagem:

> Notice: Undefined index: UsuarioNome in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\sistema\restrito.php on line 28

Tentei mudar "UsuarioID","UsuarioNome" e "UsuarioNivel" para o nome dos atributos da tabela (id, nome e nivel, respectivamente) mas eu sou redirecionada para a index e nada acontece.

Comment: `$_SESSION` é uma [superglobal](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php) então, teoricamente, ela vai sempre estar definida. Não faz sentido usar `isset` nela. Seria só dar `session_start` sem if mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Você iniciou a sessão? É preciso iniciar a sessão em todas as páginas que você precisar gravar ou recuperar alguma coisa da sessão.

```
session_start()
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php

Comment: No caso a linha "if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();" é o início da sessão, não?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` é uma [superglobal](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php) então, teoricamente, ela vai sempre estar definida. Não faz sentido usar `isset` nela pois sempre retornaria `true`.

Então o seu `if`:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

sempre retornará `false` e a sessão nunca será iniciada.

A resolução seria apenas `session_start` sem if mesmo:

```
session_start();
```

Pois na [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php) diz:

> session_start() cria uma sessão ou resume a sessão atual baseado em um id de sessão passado via GET ou POST, ou passado via cookie.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
    ...
}
```

Tente usar seu if dessa maneira